# Using CONCAT on a database table name

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to `concat` the table name with the lastDay date as a string, and have this kind of results :

`dl-recommendation-engine:NDA_CHANEL_137002018.ga_sessions_20200128`

I found this line to get me the day of yesterday

`REPLACE(CAST(DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), DAY), INTERVAL 1 DAY) as STRING), "-","")` I casted it as a string

But now I have to concat all and it doesn't work ...

````
date,
transaction.transactionId, 
ref.productSKU as productRef, 
associated.productSKU as productAssociated, 
ARRAY_LENGTH(hits.product) as nbProducts

FROM CONCAT("`dl-recommendation-engine:NDA_CHANEL_137002018.ga_sessions_",
REPLACE(CAST(DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), DAY), INTERVAL 1 DAY) as STRING), "-",""),
"`") as session,

UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
UNNEST(hits.product) as ref,
UNNEST(hits.product) as associated

AND hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL
AND ARRAY_LENGTH(hits.product) > 2```
````

Comment: You can't do this without using dynamic SQL to execute the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use _TABLE_SUFFIX?

I simplified the query by deleting unnecessary columns here:

```
SELECT *
FROM `dl-recommendation-engine:NDA_CHANEL_137002018.ga_sessions_*` as session,
WHERE 
_TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Comment: Yes that's what i did finally , thank you very much :)